# Group then Sort with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to count the number of documents associated with an ID, then sort the results. Here's an example document (in the `media` collection).

```
{
  "_id" : "00wlz2j2cu9kx",
  "uploadedBy" : { 
    "uid" : "00wen1b4tfwn6",
  }
}
```

Basically, I need to group all of these documents by `uploadedBy.uid`, sort by the resulting array by a count of documents. I have this command thus far:

```
db.media.group({
  key: {
    'uploadedBy.uid' : true
  },

  reduce: function(obj, prev) {
    prev.total += 1
  },

  initial: {
    total: 0
  }
})
```

Which gives me this array as a result.

```
[
  {
    "uploadedBy.uid" : "00wen1b4tfwn6",
    "total" : 1
  },
  {
    "uploadedBy.uid" : "00wp0s9c73dvl",
    "total" : 2
  }
]
```

Now I just need to sort each of these documents by the `total` field. How do I do this?

Comment: I suppose that would depend on the driver you're using.

Comment: I'm using the Node.js driver.

Comment: Then, I am afraid I cannot help you, I work with the Java one :)

Comment: Try this one db.media.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$uploadedBy.uid},"sum":{$sum:1}},{$sort:{"sum":1}});

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) for this, if your MongoDB version >= 2.1. Many simple aggregation queries are easier to write with it as opposed to MapReduce (the group() function you are using currently uses MapReduce under the covers).

The aggregation framework provides an easy $sort option to order your results, as follows:

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/myDb", function (err, db) {
    "use strict";
    var collection = db.collection("media"),
        resultsHandler = function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(results);
        };

    collection.aggregate(
        {
            $group: {
                _id: { uid: "$uploadedBy.uid" },
                total: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                total: -1
            }
        },
        resultsHandler
    );
});
```

Comment: You should probably make the $group _id just "$uploadedBy.uid" - there is no reason for it to be an embedded document.

Answer (score 2):

In case if node.js support aggregation framework try to use it

```
db.media.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$uploadedBy.uid', 'count': {$sum: 1}}},
    {'$sort': {'count': -1}}
])
```

I'm not sure that this code have no issues, but you can try something like this.

**EDIT**
Changed the query to work properly. This answer worked for me. You can also add skip/limit here to get top 5 results, as illustrated below:

```
db.media.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$uploadedBy.uid', 'count': {$sum: 1}}},
    {'$sort': {'count': -1}},
    {'$skip': 0},
    {'$limit': 5}
])
```

Comment: that aggregation query is wrong, you are using uid and count as _id which won't work.